# Combining filename in for loop(cat, awk)

Tags: awk, filenames, cat

In my code I want to give the name of a new file combining the old file names to one together. How this doesn't work with basename? Any idea how I can do this?

```
for i in /dir/*; do
   for j in /dir/*; do
        filename=$(basename "$i")
        filename2=$(basename "$j")
           if   grep -q E "$i" ; 
             then cat "$i" "$j" > /Path/"$filename" "$filename2".fasta
           fi
done
```

done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... > "/Path/${filename}${filename2}.fasta"
```